# How to see the actual configuration values for apache cassandra in cqlsh?

Tags: cassandra

This is what I have in cassandra.yaml

```
prepared_statements_cache_size_mb: 500MB
```

Is it possible to see the actual value of that variable once you're in cqlsh?

Comment: actual value - you mean how much is consumed? or configured value?

Comment: @AlexOtt - configured value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because CQL statements are sent to the cluster (which should be three or more nodes), you can't use CQL to read settings on an individual node.  The value for prepared_statements_cache is just for that node.

You could use JMX to read [org.apache.cassandra.config.Config](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/latest/org/apache/cassandra/config/Config.html) on a node, including prepared_statements_cache_size_mb.

Answer (score 4):

Since Cassandra 4.0 you'll able to do that by reading from `system_views.settings` table.

See the [blog post from TLP on topic of virtual tables](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/03/08/virtual-tables-in-cassandra-4_0.html)...